# USB CDC (VCP/UART) optional endpoint

Tags: usb, stm32f4

I'm developing an USB application for a STM32 MCU.

For now I have 2 interfaces for CCID classes and I want to add another for a Virtual COM Port. On a STM32F4, The limit of IN endpoint in FullSpeed is 5 plus one reserved for control (80). I already used 4 IN endpoint for the CCIDs.

**Does Interupt IN for CDC class is optional?**

I think i have to declare 3 endpoints like this:

- Bulk IN
- Bulk OUT
- Interupt IN

Note : I know that in HighSpeed there is 7 endpoint available but i don't have time to develop a custom board (need an external phy chip and other things).

Comment: Just a side note: On STM32, you need an external PHY with the USB HS *only* if you actually want it to run at high-speed. If full-speed is sufficient, you can use the integrated full-speed PHY of the USB HS peripheral (there is one).

Comment: The CDC specification says that the notification endpoint is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notification endpoint is optional, as CL said, however I wouldn't count on proper driver support.

Comment: I will try without Notification endpoint for now. If it really not supported by the windows driver i will use @dim's solution anyway.